# Add Existing Virtual Network to Function App Creation -Terraform Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

```
#access existing application insight
data "azurerm_application_insights" "dev"{
  name                = var.tf_var_app_insights_name
  resource_group_name = var.tf_var_rg_name
}

#################step-1 function app creation
data "azurerm_service_plan" "dev" {
  name                = var.tf_var_app_service_plan
  resource_group_name = var.tf_var_rg_name
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "dev" {
  name                     = var.tfvarstname
  resource_group_name      = var.tf_var_rg_name
}

#create function app
resource azurerm_windows_function_app "dev" {
  name                       = var.tf_var_rg_functionapp 
  resource_group_name        = var.tf_var_rg_name
  storage_account_name       = var.tfvarstname
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.dev.primary_access_key
  location                   = var.tf_var_rg_location
  service_plan_id            = data.azurerm_service_plan.dev.id 
  functions_extension_version   =var.tf_var_function_extention_version
  auth_settings  {
     enabled = true 
     active_directory  {
         client_id = var.tf_var_client_id
         client_secret = var.tf_var_client_secret
         #client_secret_setting_name  = "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET"
     }
     default_provider = var.tf_var_provider
     issuer = var.tf_var_issuer
  }
  site_config{
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = var.tf_var_dot_net_version
    }
    application_insights_key =data.azurerm_application_insights.dev.instrumentation_key
  } 
  tags ={
    environment = var.tf_var_tags_environment
    application_name =var.tf_var_tags_application_name
    function_name =var.tf_var_tags_function_name
  }
  
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "dev" {
  name                =  var.tf_var_virtual_network_name
  resource_group_name = var.tf_var_rg_name
}
output "vnet_id" {
 value =  data.azurerm_virtual_network.dev.id
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "dev" {
  name                 = var.tf_var_subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.tf_var_rg_name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.dev.name
}
output "subnet_id" {
 value= data.azurerm_subnet.dev.id
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "dev" {
  app_service_id = data.azurerm_service_plan.dev.id
  subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.dev.id
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.dev, azurerm_windows_function_app.dev]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

The error message is below [image: error].I am trying to create a function app using existing resources. All the other parts are working. I just need a little support on virtual network integration. If anyone can support that will be great.

I tried to add

```
depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.dev, azurerm_windows_function_app.dev]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
```

but it did not work anywhere. I need a little support on what am I missing ?

Comment: To resolve this error, you need to change the app_service_id to point to the azurerm_windows_function_app resource ID instead of the azurerm_service_plan data ID. i.e.,
app_service_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.dev.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving Credit to [Vinay B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21951576/vinay-b), the answer is to add function app id instead of app service plan id

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "dev" {
   # service_plan_id = data.azurerm_service_plan.dev.id
   app_service_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.dev.id
  subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.dev.id
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.dev, azurerm_windows_function_app.dev]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      subnet_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm providing the in-detail solution which I suggested @Nithila.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to Add an Existing Virtual Network to Function App Creation using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

You are attempting to create an Azure Function App with a Virtual Network (VNet) integration using existing resources, according to the configuration you shared. The error message "ID was missing the 'sites' element" indicates that the ID of the App Service (or Function App) is not referenced correctly.

You need to specify an `app_service_id` for the Terraform resource `azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection`. This ID should refer to either an Azure Function App or an App Service. However, you have given the ID of a service plan in your code, which is incorrect:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "dev" {
  app_service_id = data.azurerm_service_plan.dev.id
...
}
```

You need to use the ID of the `azurerm_windows_function_app` resource that you created earlier, not the service plan. The service plan ID is missing the 'sites' element, which is required for an App Service or Function App ID.

**My terraform configuration: **

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Create a new Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vksb-rg"
  location = "east us"
}

# Create a new Storage Account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "vksbstacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

# Create a new Service Plan
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-serviceplan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type = "Windows"

  sku_name = "S1"  # This combines the tier and size into one attribute
}

# Create a new Application Insights
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-appinsights"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

# Create a new Function App
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-functionapp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
 

  site_config {
    
  }

  app_settings = {
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING" = "InstrumentationKey=${azurerm_application_insights.example.instrumentation_key}"
  }
}

# Create a new Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Create a new Subnet with a delegation for Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Sql"]

  delegation {
    name = "functionappdelegation"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
  }
}


# Integrate the Function App with the Virtual Network using the appropriate resource type
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

&

[image]

Comment: This will create all I wanted to ad existing one